# Как подсказать браузеру где на странице брать контент для Режима чтения?

Tags: html, css, firefox, браузер

Я об этой функции в Firefox:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Существует ли какой-то html-тег для этого, или можно дать блоку какой-то класс для обозначения "главного" текста на странице?

Проблема в том, что на каких-то страницах моего сайта браузер дает возможность просмотреть статью в режиме чтения, а на каких-то нет.

Взять тот же Хабр, в [этой](https://habrahabr.ru/company/infoculture/blog/316186/) статье кнопка появляется, а в [этой](https://habrahabr.ru/company/infoculture/blog/318596/) нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ прост - соблюдать семантику в HTML-разметке. Рекомендую прочитать про HTML5-теги. Согласно его стандартам, основной текст на странице нужно помещать в Тег `article`. Как это реализовано, можно посмотреть на примере моей последней [работы](http://1000.tech/ru/godlike.css). Там реализована семантическая разметка и сайт отлично читается на мобильном Safari. На Windows не проверял, но скорее всего там принцип работы идентичный.

Comment: `article` или всё-таки `main`?

Comment: main - это главный контент, а в article - непосредственно сама статья.